# Error AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Olá,

Estou aplicando a seguinte função no meu controller do AngularJS:

```
$scope.cancelChanges = function() {
        $scope.name = $scope.namebackup;
        $scope.$apply();
    };
```

Porém, ao executar o $apply(), ele me mostra o seguinte erro:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at Error (native)
    at http://local/vendor/bower/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
    at m (http://local/vendor/bower/angular/angular.min.js:101:443)
    at h.$apply (http://local/vendor/bower/angular/angular.min.js:108:301)
```

alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente o erro do seu código é que o $apply recebe como parâmetro uma função para ser executada.

Então, a forma correta de escrever esse código seria:

```
$scope.cancelChanges = function() {
    $scope.$apply( function() {
        $scope.name = $scope.namebackup;
    } );
};
```

Porém, achei estranha a sua necessidade para um $apply nesse curto exemplo. A menos que a função cancelChanges() esteja sendo invocada a partir de algum código JS que não faz parte da app angular (um plugin JQuery por exemplo), então o $apply é redundante. E se for esse o caso, você vai receber um novo erro (diferente do primeiro) dizendo que o digest já está acontecendo e que a chamada ao $apply é redundante.

**UPDATE**

Na verdade li rápido seu erro. Se você colar o link que ele te mostra no erro (http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply) você verá uma página da documentação do angular explicando melhor o problema. Nesse caso, realmente é possível que o $apply seja invocado sem uma expressão. O real problema é que o digest já está acontecendo e a sua chamada ao $apply é redundante.

Então basta remover ela que tudo deve funcionar bem.

Comment: O problema é que quando só faço o $scope.name = $scope.namebackup ele não atualiza minha view, ele só atualiza o meu scope @loreno-oliveira

Comment: Você pode editar o tópico e adicionar o html?

Comment: consegui resolver mas apenas tirando os parenteses do apply :D